# Firebase Analytics ecommerce events not showing "items" parameter

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I have a Xamarin app. Both apps (android and ios) are connected to a firebase project which is linked to a GA4 account.

I have successfully logged the e-commerce events through the instructions in the Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/measure-ecommerce), however, I encountered some issues.

In all of my e-commerce events, the "items" parameter does not show in GA4. If I check the e-commerce events on the reports I can see all the other parameters, however, when I try to see item_id, item_name, etc. they do not show up in GA4.

Items show on Debug View for all the e-commerce events but in the Events option (both GA4 and Firebase)  there is no way to visualize the "items" parameter.

[items showing in Debug View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfPUz.png)

Also noticed that for the event "add_to_cart" there are additional cards like "Top Products". So far I couldn't find any other e-commerce event that shows additional cards like that, not even the "purchase" event.

[Top Products card in add_to_cart event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L40kS.png)

Haven't tried Google Tag Manager or BigQuery.

Is there any way to visualize items for all the e-commerce events that require it in GA4 or outside GA4?